# Converting IQueryable to IEnumerable reduces item count

Tags: c#, linq

I do have a problem on converting `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`, the data that I'm trying to convert comes from a data store and I know all data is unique. When I tried to convert `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` or `List` the item count shows different. The item count from `IQueryable` is 161 which is same when I query directly to DB but when converted it becomes 31.

```
public IQueryable<ActiveProject> GetActiveProjects()
{
    return this._context.Set<ActiveProject>().AsNoTracking();
}
```

```
IQueryable<ActiveProject> temp = _repo.Project.GetActiveProjects().AsQueryable();

var a = temp.Count();                // 161
var b = temp.AsEnumerable().Count(); // 31
```

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: There's a `Where` filter right there in the tiny screenshot.

Comment: Already updated, the question. The `GetActiveProjects` is a repository pattern query to database.

Comment: @Blindy the `Where` clause is already disabled but still, its returning different numbers as shown on the screenshot the a is `161` and b is `31`

Comment: @BryanDellinger tried the top answer but didn't work

Comment: You are sure it's unique? What happens if you did ```var a = temp.Distinct().Count();```?

Comment: @schwechel I tried the distinct but it returns an error

`Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlFunctionExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.` on which I think similar to this issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16722

Comment: @EdwardFitzAbucay I do believe a `where` is not disabled somewhere, and the suggested duplicate is indeed the duplicate.

Comment: @GSerg okay I'll try to look into that

Comment: If you still have issues you may want to post your model as well.